# Conditional LINQ query on self-joining table with 2 sets of data

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out how to perform a conditional query on an Employees table to bring back all of their assigned Projects, but the caveat I don't quite understand on how to implement is that for every Employee, there is 0 to 1 EmployeeAssistant (self-joining entity).  So when I select EmployeeID=2 and it has an EmployeeAssistantID=5, I would like to display all of the Projects for both of these individuals, i.e. the main Employee (EmployeeID=2) and their assistant (EmployeeID=5).

The tables look like:

```
Employees
 - EmployeeID  -- (Pkey)
 - EmployeeAssistantID --  (Fkey to Employees.EmployeeID)
 - other fields
```

-

```
Projects
 - ProjectID  --  (PKey)
 - EmployeeID  -- (Fkey to Employees.EmployeeID)
 - other fields
```

I attempted the following in LINQ:

```
var projects = Projects.Include(proj => proj.Employee)
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            proj.ProjectID,
                            proj.ProjectName,
                            proj.Employee.Name
                            // ... not sure how to bring back another layer of projects for the EmployeeAssistant?
                        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Linq query to get the data you want:

```
var query = from e in Employees
            join a in Employees on e.EmployeeAssistantID equals a.EmployeeID
            where e.EmployeeID == 2
            select new
            {
               EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
               AssistantID = a.EmployeeID,
               EmployeeProjects = Projects.Where(p => p.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeID),
               AssistantProjects = Projects.Where(p => p.EmployeeID == a.EmployeeID)
            };
```

The anonymous type returned by the query contains all of the data from both employee entities, as well as all of the Project data of each employee (some can be the same, others might differ).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean to do the following:

```
var employeeIDs = new[] { myEmployee.EmployeeID, myEmployee.EmployeeAssistantID };
var projects = Projects.Where(p => employeeIds.Contains(p.EmployeeID));
```

This will grab all projects that both the employee and the assistant have done, given a previously grabbed `Employee` record (which I've called `myEmployee`).